# Android - OutOfMemoryError [ memory exhausted ]

Tags: android, memory

I Just want to understand what does memory exhausted means?

Does it mean that the memory is full or not.  I tried to look up for clear explanation of memory exhausted but couldnt find one.

Comment: Yes, "exhausted" = "all used up" in this case.

Comment: Would increasing the memory of the vm am working on solve the problem ?@BRPocock

Comment: You'd need to provide a whole lot more information about what you're doing, &c to be able to say for sure. But, in general, if you're running out of something, having more might help. Unless you're trying to use an infinite amount of it.